# Need help remembering a Space movie!

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

Can't remember a whole lot but it's a Space movie where a guy boards on with his ex wife/girlfriend and shes like a doctor who examines them and gives them daily shots. There are about 4-5 crew members and they find an Earth like planet which is a ghost town until they go in a building and the people they find are acting weird and give the crew weird green goopy soup. I don't remember much else but one of the crew members goes off with a girl and doesn't come back I think.

Comment: You have a decent start here could you have a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) to see if there are any other details you can [edit] into the question. For example, when did you see it?

Comment: Not sure about it, but Pandorum shares some similarities with what you described.
Like said earlier, can you be more precise ?

Comment: Do you remember when you watched? Did they have personal computers on it or was it more like Star Trek Original Series? Any robots?

Answer (score 5):

The green soup and the ghost town sounds like [400 Days](http://www.400daysthemovie.com) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/400_Days_(film))).

[image: Green Soup]

There is a four person crew with a similar relationship dynamic… the ships Doctor/Physcologist was his fiancée not his wife, but she bailed on him. She administers immunisation boosters regularly.

[image: Shots]

The big guy "Cole", getting the shot above, is the one that goes to the bar and disappears after meeting up with a women he's convinced was at their "launch" ceremony.

The other difference is that they are on a 400 day long simulation of a space flight not an actual flight.

According to the people from the town

> The moon was destroyed by something, resulting in a dust cloud that covered the world… bringing about the end of civilisation.

Comment: This looks really like another film I saw a few years ago, and now I want to figure out what that one was...

Comment: The OP describes "400 Days" pretty accurately other than the space part, so is there a definite scene of a spaceship?

Comment: No, they descend into a bunker. The only spacecraft are in the opening credits and are historical footage of previous space going vehicles played under sections of speeches by Reagan and Obama.